# How to form render array from multiple APIs in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise

## Situation

I need to form a comments timeline which looks like this,

[image: Result]

Yet the information comes from 2 different APIs,

[image]

#### API Format

**1.** **Comments API**, an array of comments by chronological order

```json
[
  {
    comment: 'Hello, how's your day?',
    userId: '001',
    timestamp: '1670548338131'
  },
  {
    comment: 'Pretty good!',
    userId: '002',
    timestamp: '1670548338151'
  },
  {
    comment: 'Want to hang out later?',
    userId: '001',
    timestamp: '1670548338171'
  },
  ...
]
```

**2.** **User info API**, 1 user info per search

```json
{
  userId: '001',
  userName: 'Ben',
  userProfileUrl: 'https://www.photo.com/001'
}
```

## Questions

1. What's the better way to call *API 2* mutiple times?
2. What's the better way to form the render array? (Want the highest efficiency)

> Although modifying the backend data model would be ideal, I'm under some constraints that I can only manipulate data on the frontend.

## Initial Idea

1. Fetch comments list first, use a `Set` to collect unique `userIds`
2. Use `Promise.all` to fetch API 2 parallelly with all the `userIds` within the Set
3. Form a dictionary (map) to lookup user info by `userId`
4. Iterate the list from step 1, fill in user info one by one, and produce a new list
5. Set the final result list into `useState` state
6. Render

```js
const getComments = () => axios.get('API_1')
const getUser = (userId) => axios.get(`API_2/${userId}`)

const [renderList, setRenderList] = React.useState([])

const initComments = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await getComments()
    const rawComments = res.data
    const usersSet = new Set(rawComments.map(c => c.userId))
    const promises = [...usersSet].map(u => getUser(u))

    // Here's the question 1, is it viable?
    const usersInfo = await Promise.all(promises)
    const usersMap = usersInfo.reduce((prev, curr) => {
      return {
        ...prev,
        [curr.data.userId]: curr.data,
      }
    }, {})

    // Here's the question 2, is it the most efficient way?
    const finalList = rawComments.map(c => {
      return {
        ...c,
        userName: usersMap[c.userId].userName,
        userProfileUrl: usersMap[c.userId].userProfileUrl,
      }
    })
    setRenderList(finalList)
  } catch(err) {}
}

React.useEffect(() => {
  initComments()
}, [])

return renderList.map(item => <>{/* Do the render here */}</>)
```

Comment: If you have a working solution, share what you don't like about it. 'Better' is quite subjective if this is not further qualified.

Comment: Better in time complexity efficiency-wise.

Comment: Are you having performance problems, or is the question theoretical?

Comment: Not having a performance problem so far. This is the first time I encounter this use case, I'd like to have some experienced developers' input on whether there's space for optimization.

Comment: We can do a `populate` query on user model to join comments and users data, in that way there will be no need of calling two api's.

Comment: @MohammedShahed I can only manipulate data on the FE due to some constrains.

Comment: @BugmanHuang over-optimizing for cases like these is almost always a bad idea. You might get a few more CPU cycles out but at the cost of legibility. 99% of the time spent by your code will be sending/waiting for data in the network.

Comment: That said, your code looks pretty good already.

Comment: you may try https://codereview.stackexchange.com, people there are more picky :P